# 32amp single phase or three phase

Tags: three-phase, single-phase

Sorry if there is a straight forward answer but my partner has converted a trailer into a drinks unit. She has a fridge a freezer and a coffee machine. Also about 5double sockets and lighting. 
The question we are stumped on is when applying for venues they asked which 32amp we need single or three? and I haven't the foggiest .
If anyone could help would be so grateful.

Many thanks

James

Comment: What country? You give no clue in your question or user profile.

Comment: If the thing will work with a single 32 Amp circuit, I'd go with single phase, assuming that 3-phase power is not universally available.  You could make an adaptor cable to permit a single-phase connector to be plugged into a 3-phase outlet, using only one phase, just in case you find a venue that has only three-phase outlets.

Comment: Show a photo of your trailer fuseboard and the plug on the mains lead to your trailer.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest question will be what the fridge and freezer takes, single-phase or three-phase ... only you, your partner, or electrician can answer that.

Comment: I thought only the stove used three-phase.

Comment: Be careful here! On past experience when a snackwaggon talks about a coffee machine it can mean anything from a little single phase thing plugged into a domestic socket up to some sort of monster expresso rig with loads of chrome and live steam from a 10kW boiler! If single phase is all you need then that is far more commonly available, but if you need three phase, you need three phase.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you are in Europe.

[image] 
[image]

*Figure 1. 32 A single phase plug and socket (left) and 3-phase (right).*

The single-phase connectors have three pins: live (L), neutral (N) and earth (E).

The three-phase connectors have five pins: live 1 (L1), live 2 (L2), live 3 (L3), neutral (N) and earth (E).

It is more than likely that your trailer has been wired for single phase.